# Unknown base64 like encoding

Tags: encoding, base64

I am trying to generate a configuration file for wirecast (.wsct). I want to set the username and password for the output. The problem is that the password is encoded in some way.

I can encode strings manually examples below

```
text       unknown-encoded  base64-encoded
a          og==             YQo=
password   Pp/nD+RP/WU=     cGFzc3dvcmQK
test123    t5RSTbhuCg==     dGVzdDEyMwo=

<output ... output_username="asd" output_password="t5RSTbhuCg==" ... />
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Any chance that the password is first encrypted, then b64encoded? It seems like a reasonable thing to do given that the password is stored on the disk. From the samples give, it doesn't look like a simple xor or anything like that. It doesn't look like a block cipher either, because `a` maps to a single encoded character.

What's the application written in? Maybe you can disassemble that part fairly easily (in case of .net / java / ...).

The encoding is likely to be `base64`, because the padding at the end matches (at least in the examples you provided).

Comment: That's very true, I would also encrypt it somehow.
A couple of a's encode to this when unbase64: 83 53 96 5D 00 D7 22 93 02 B4 3D 90.
Even more a's: 83 53 96 5D 35 BC 19 CF 83 53 96 5D 35 BC 19 CF 83 53 96 5D 35 BC 19 CF 83 53 96 5D 35 BC 19 CF 83 53 96 5D 35 BC 19 CF 83 53 96 6F A4 71 9D 7D 36 00 2D.
The program is written in objective c / c.

Comment: Ok - that's quite interesting. So here are more facts: the key is not changing; block length is 8 bytes; there is no feedback between the blocks (8 bytes full of 'a' keep repeating in your example). Maybe you can check if the application is linked to some ssl library?

Comment: Also it looks like a stream cipher, rather than a block one (maybe the key is repeating 8 bytes?) because just `a` is actually reduced to 1 encrypted byte. (ok - maybe not a stream cipher really, but definitely something that can have the rest of the assumed 8-byte block dropped without issues)

Answer (score 0):

You are not consistent, "a" is encoded as 0x83 or 0xA2?
"og==" is decoded to 0xA2, while in comment you say that couple of a's encode to 0x83...

If you know encrypted text and plaintext, you can try to use this program:

```
import struct
import base64

# data to decrypt
todecrypt = base64.b64decode('t5RSTbhuCg==')

# known plaintext and its encrypted equivalent
known_encrypted = base64.b64decode('Pp/nD+RP/WU=')
known_plaintext = b'password'

# determine an encryption key
key = b''.join([struct.pack('B', known_encrypted[i] ^ known_plaintext[i]) for i in range(len(known_encrypted))])

# decrypt data
decrypted = b''.join([struct.pack('B', todecrypt[i] ^ key[i]) for i in range(len(todecrypt))])
print('key', key)
print('decrypted', decrypted)
```

If decrypted data doesn't match (test123 was assumed), this means that stream **cipher like RC4** is used.